# CSS Resizable content

Tags: html, css, resize

I'm trying to make a website (for phone and tablet users) with a maximum width of 500px, and without minimum width.

Both of the corners have a images, which should not be resized, and the middle one should resize in a space left from corner images. (i don't want to use javascript)
So can anyone help me with this problem?

Here's my css and html code:

```
#container {
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
#top_left{
background: url( '../images/top_left.png' ) no-repeat;
width: 19px;
height: 48px;
float: left;
}
#top_center {
background: url( '../images/top_mid.png' ) repeat-x;
max-width: 461px;
height: 48px;
float: left;
}
#top_right {
background: url( '../images/top_right.png' ) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
height: 48px;
float: right;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="top_left"></div>
  <div id="top_center"></div>
  <div id="top_right"></div>
  <div class="cb"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the actual problem you want helping with?

Comment: I want to make middle image resizable up to 461px, but when i do max-width: 461px; the image dissapears. When i write width: 90% and i try to resize it, the corner images drops, becouse middle one is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use @media queries in your CSS to determine page size for phones and tablets. you can set the website to adjust based on the size of the screen that the person is using.

for instance, if your website has two columns. you can set it up so that at a screen size similar to a tablet, both columns are side-be-side. then, if it is accessed on a phone, it would move the second column down below the first to change the page to a one column layout.

unfortunately since you don't want to use scripts, getting menus and other things of that nature to work properly on both devices will be a tedious task. the smaller screen real estate on a phone generally forces people to set their menus up differently than they would on larger devices such as tablets and pc's. I know you said you don't want to use scripts, but it may be a good option to look into if you want to design effectively.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Here is a link to a webpage that gives examples of how to use CSS media queries.

Comment: Thank you, Jason, for your answer. 
I checked on those media queries, but it's not what i'm looking for.
I made a fast jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJxvK/ when you open it, the left, right, and middle backgrounds stay in one line, but when you try to resize it, backgrounds from corners moves up and down. I'm trying to  make them stay in one line when resizing browser.